# stdio example in Rust book uses unstable library feature 'old_io' - what alternatives exist?

Tags: rust

I have the following Rust code taken from the [Rust book](http://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0-alpha.2/book/standard-input.html):

```
fn main() {
println!("Type something: ");

let input = std::old_io::stdin().read_line().ok().expect("Failed to read line!");

println!("Here's what you said: {}", input);
}
```

When I compile this example using `rustc hello.rs` I get the following output:

```
hello.rs:4:38: 4:49 error: use of unstable library feature 'old_io'
hello.rs:4     let input = std::old_io::stdin().read_line().ok().expect("Failed
to read line!");
                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~
hello.rs:4:49: 4:49 help: add #![feature(old_io)] to the crate attributes to ena
ble
hello.rs:4:17: 4:35 error: use of unstable library feature 'old_io'
hello.rs:4     let input = std::old_io::stdin().read_line().ok().expect("Failed
to read line!");
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
hello.rs:4:35: 4:35 help: add #![feature(old_io)] to the crate attributes to ena
ble
hello.rs:4:38: 4:49 warning: use of deprecated item, #[warn(deprecated)] on by d
efault
hello.rs:4     let input = std::old_io::stdin().read_line().ok().expect("Failed
to read line!");
                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~
hello.rs:4:17: 4:35 warning: use of deprecated item, #[warn(deprecated)] on by d
efault
hello.rs:4     let input = std::old_io::stdin().read_line().ok().expect("Failed
to read line!");
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

The documentation author doesn't seem to have problems compiling (or if he/she does, they do not indicate any way to remedy it). Using `std::io` will give a similar error. What are my options here?

Comment: Hey @Shepmaster, the book starts talking about IO here: http://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0-alpha.2/book/standard-input.html . The author doesn't seem to have problems compiling (or if he/she does, they do not indicate any way to remedy it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be [bug 23760](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/23760). As a work around, do

```
fn main() {
    println!("Type something: ");

    let mut s = String::new();
    let count = std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut s).ok().expect("Failed to read line!");

    println!("Here's what you said: {} ({} bytes)", s, count);
}
```

Unfortunately, as [Steve points out](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/23760#issuecomment-86746458):

> These are the [examples] we can't run automated tests for :(

Comment: This compiles, but when I run it I get a strange result: 
    `Type something:
    Good Morning
    Here's what you said : 15`

Comment: Ah, its simply the last line: instead of `println!("Here's what you said : {}", input)` it should be `println!("Here's what you said: {}", s);`.

Comment: @noobProgrammer yup, fixed now. The string is read into `s` and the count of bytes read is the result value. Silly me!